# Switching between data in the same component angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to learn angular making a game using SSE Emitter. The game purpose is two with two players answer to a random question. For a faster explanation I will give this scenario as example:

*We have 6 players:*

- player 1
- player 2

with question *5*

- player 3
- player 4

with question *17*

- player 5
- player 6

with question *21*

Every player answer to a question, after that all players are redirected to the vote section:
Here I created the next view:

[image: vote view]

So, till now what happen is: I am on **localhost:4200/answer/112233**(game code) -> all users vote -> all users should be redirected to **localhost:4200/vote/112233** (As a PS: To be honest, I don't know how to redirect all users to the new route - I don't know if router.navigate is enough, I didn't tested this part yet..)

I use localStorage in different tab containers for identifying the users.
(myData: {name:"userName", id: "userId"})

**The big problem:**

What I did till now: In the vote section, I made a service which call all the answers for the 6 players from the db.

How I think I should continue (if it can be made without SSE emitter interaction it would be great):
So, what I need to do is saving player 1 and player 2 states in the ts variables, after player 3 and player 4 states and, finally the 5th and 6th players state. How can I do that? I read a little about ViewChild / ViewChildren, but I don't know if that will help me. In case of help, should I make a new component or something?

Comment: Do all players play on the same device ?

Comment: Yes, that's why I use an addon on mozilla for different containers. In this way every user has a different localStorage. I kinda simulate a different browser interaction.

Comment: I think your solution is overcompliated if you only need to have multiples users on the same device, why not use array ?

Comment: Because, in the end they will not play on the same browser. Like I said, I use mozilla addon for different containers. Just like a different browser. The purpose is to play from your browser, so different pc. LocalStorage has the purpose to identify the current user. But my problem is how I can switch between screens without changing the route. Like making a for(i=0;i<n;i+=2) and having a[i] & a[i+1]; I will save them in current state of the browser, make game logic(with the vote), and after (n-1)/2 players vote the same logic for next iteration.

Comment: Anyway I can do that with a new column in db and using router.navigate, but i wanted to know if there is a directive for changing the logic data(I kinda mean the state of the page), so the screens actually, without redirecting..